Excel Macro - Delete rows based on multiple or statements
I am trying to write a macro that deletes rows based on a certain criteria. The macro I currently have works, but it does not allow for 30 values. I receive the "Too Many Line Continuations" error after line 25.
I would like to delete all rows that do not contain the 30 fields listed, and keep the header row.
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim row_count As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim my_string As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

ws.Activate
row_count = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

Do While i <= row_count

    my_string = ws.Cells(i, 5).Text
    
    If InStr(my_string, "A") = 0 _
    And InStr(my_string, "B") = 0 _
    And InStr(my_string, "C") = 0 _
    And InStr(my_string, "D") = 0 _
    And InStr(my_string, "E") = 0 _
    And InStr(my_string, "F") = 0 _
    And InStr(my_string, "G") = 0 Then
    
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
        row_count = row_count - 1
    
    End If

i = i + 1

    
Loop
End Sub


You can use an array for the 30 fields and an inner loop through this array.

To add to BigBens comment:
Dim CharArray(29) As String
CharArray(0) = "A"
CharArray(1) = "B"
CharArray(2) = "C"

Etc
Then for the If statement:
Do While i <= row_count

    my_string = ws.Cells(i, 5).Text
    
    For j = 0 To 29
        If InStr(my_string, CharArray(j)) = 1 Then
            GoTo Skip
        End If
    Next
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
        row_count = row_count - 1
Skip:
i = i + 1

    
Loop
End Sub

This Loops through all Conditions and if 1 is not a 0 then it will skip.
